# Windows 7 Explorer cannot sort files alphabetically

Tags: file, sorting, windows-7, explorer

I use sort by + name, and explorer cannot sort my files by name. How can they screw up something so easy?

Is there any magic registry way to do this, here is the explorer output and dir output. I want the `dir` version of course.

[image]

[image]

Comment: right click in the folder, sort by, name.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/415629/sort-order-in-windows-explorer

Answer (score 5):

Windows 7's sort is an absolute joke.  The rubbish above about natural sorting is no excuse - I don't know anyone who would naturally sort "Back to the Future 3" before "Back to the Future" for example, and other languages existed pre Windows 7.

The fix can be found here:

http://www.alliancegroup.co.uk/windows7-explorer-sort-order.htm

And in case the link dies:

- Type gpedit.msc in the Start menu’s search box and then press Enter.
- Navigate to User Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components, and then select Windows Explorer in the left column of the Group Policy editor.
- Double-click Turn off numerical sorting in Windows Explorer in the Settings section of the Group Policy editor.
- Select Enable and then click OK to save the changes.

Comment: The link has dead. And to a human being, correct lexicographically sort doesn't make sense in most cases. I bet almost everyone will shout at Windows when it sorts in order of 1, 10, 100, 11, 12, 2, 20, 21, 3... That's why explorer uses natural sort instead of your joking sort https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought I was going crazy. Explorer just refused to sort my photos from different sources by year, even though they all started with the correct four digits. Your fix still works in Windows 10!

Answer (score 2):

It's not screwed up at all, it's by design.

There are a lot of things to consider when sorting, for example non-English languages can do sorting completely differently. The DIR command however ignores all this and does a 'stupid' sort. Explorer is for end users and therefore tries to sort the way users expect.

Here's an article with some info:
[Why, when you sort by name, doesn't it actually sort by name?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/04/8824356.aspx)
[What order does the DIR command arrange files if no sort order is specified?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/03/04/10504812.aspx)
[String sorting is not done by ASCII code any more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/18/134051.aspx)